# Trying to call function with onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function with onclick but when I click the button nothing happens. I have seen the table appear before I tried adding an onclick. Here is the code.

```
<body>
        
        <button onclick="createSheet()">Display</button>   
        <div id="tableContainer"></div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var totalQuestions;
        function createSheet() {
          var sheet = "";
          totalQuestions = 8;
      
          sheet += "<div><table>";
          for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
            sheet += "<tr>";
            sheet += "<td class='question'>";
            sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "A" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
            sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
            sheet += "</td>";
            sheet += "<td class='question'>";
            sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "B" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
            sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
            sheet += "</td>";
            sheet += "<td class='question'>";
            sheet += "<div class='questionNumber'>" + "C" + (i + 1) + "</div>";
            sheet += "<div class='qContent'>" + addition2() + " </div>";
            sheet += "</td>";
            sheet += "</tr>";
          }
          
          sheet += "</table></div>"; 
          document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHtml = sheet;
        
        }
              
        function addition2() {
          var difficulty = 1000;
          var ans;
              
          for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
            var numGen = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
            var numGen1 = Math.round(Math.random() * difficulty + 100);
            var question = numGen  +  " + "  +  numGen1
            var ans = numGen + numGen1
          } 
          
          return question;
        }
      </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Typo. The property you are looking for is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: omg thanks been annoying me for a while now :/

Comment: use innerHTML not innerHtml

Answer (score 1):

Switch

```js
document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHtml = sheet;
```

to

```js
document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = sheet;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error at

```
document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHtml = sheet;
```

It should be

```
document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = sheet;
```